# his only son that . .

Tags: relative-pronouns

Is the following sentence okay? Does it imply that the person has more than one son?

> His **only son that** lives in New York is visiting him this Friday.

Comment: No - it specifically means ***he has only one son*** (and *that* son lives in NY, but it would be more natural to refer to him as the man's only son ***who*** lives in NY, not ***that*** lives there).

Comment: I'll be here, waiting for your comments that clarify the situation. Are you specifically referring to **restrictive clauses**?

Comment: Have you created this sentence to test your understanding of how restrictive clauses work?  It seems to be a very odd and artificial construction.  If someone wants to let you know that they have several sons, there are easier ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the sentence implies that he has more than one son ("his son *that lives in NY*"). But it also implies that he has only one son ("his *only* son"). So it is not a good sentence.

Turning the clause into a parenthetical phrase will solve the problem:

> His son, who lives in New York, is visiting him this Friday.

If you want to make it clear that he has just the one son:

> His only son, who lives in New York, is visiting him this Friday.

Using "that lives" or "what lives" instead of "who lives" is colloquial usage and would not be considered correct in formal writing.

Comment: Are you saying  the phrase "His **only son** that lives in NY" suggests that the man may have other sons who are living in different cities?

Comment: "what lives" would sound quite abnormal in AmE, although it is usual in some UK dialect, i understand.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I think the original can be read to imply more than one son, as I say in my answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel That is making a simple statement more complicated than is necessary.The phrase "his only son" could also suggest someone who has several daughters but *only* one son. What could "His only child who lives in NY" possibly mean?  Is that also ambiguous? The adverb "only" clearly modifies the noun. Why use it if someone has several children?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Like David says, I think "his son that lives in NY" implies the existence of other sons who don't, while "his only son" implies the non-existence of other sons. The sentence contradicts itself. You could *try* to interpret it as "the only one of his sons who lives in NY" but that is not 100% clear.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  I would say it is. It could mean that he has several children, but only one lives in NY. It may well be that the speaker will tolerate this ambiguity, either because it doesn't much matter or other context will make the matter clear. But since the question raised the point, it seems to matter to the OP. To banish the ambiguity at least the appositive commas should be used. But is speech that isn't enough, even in writing this can easily be misread. Rephrasing to clarify seems a better choice to me. There may be better ways than my suggestion.

Comment: Does "his only house that is in New York" have the same problem as "his only son that lives in New York"?

Comment: @Apollyon yes, it's the exact same ambiguity (and contradiction). You could say "his only New York house" to mean "the only one of his multiple houses which is in New York," if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be read to imply that. Specifically it could be understood as saying that he has more than one son, but only one lives in New York. It is an awkward and ambiguous sentence, whether there is another son or not. Also it is far more usual to refer to a person with "who" instead of "that".

Technically, if the clause is non-restrictive, because "only son" has already fully defined the son (that is answered the question "which son"), it should be  placed between commas:

> His only son, who lives in New York, is visiting him this Friday.

But I think this is still putting a lot of weight on a pair of commas, although it is clearer and more grammatical than the original.

Something like:

> His only son, Mark, lives in New York. Mark is visiting him this Friday.

would be free from any possible ambiguity, and gives additional information besides. It is a bit more wordy, but I think it reads better. That is a matter of style, however.

Comment: Idiomatically, I'd say that ***no-one*** would ever use the construction *His **only son** that [meets some criterion]* to mean *The **only one of his multiple sons** [who meets that criterion]*, so the possible "ambiguity" only exists for non-native speakers. But I'll reverse my impending downvote if you come up with an example of a competent writer doing this.

Comment: It would be an unusual construction I admit, most likely  done as a form of word-play on the same lines as "what's that in the road ahead (a head)". I also can't think of a good way to search for such a usage. I still maintain that the ambiguity is possible, an easy enough to remove.  the form "*His son, who lives in New York, is visiting him this Friday.*" is probably enough for most speakers. It seems that randomhead also sees an ambiguity here.

Comment: My only son who plays the trumpet has red hair; My only son, who plays the trumpet, has red hair

Comment: @Michael Yes, i understand the distinction, but particualrly in spoke English is that distinction always made clear? Even in written text, a careless reader can be confused, in my view.

Comment: For the second, I'd make a slight pause after 'son'.

Comment: @Michael Yes, but not all speakers are careful in inserting such pauses. Also, not all listeners are attentive to such pauses.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers that the example sentence is something that native speakers would never say. It has a strong whiff of concoction about it. It offers unnecessary information, and reminds me of the old 'Jewish mother' joke punch line 'Help! My son the doctor is drowning!' (told me by the local rabbi).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - speaking of concocting sentences, I am pretty sure that I remember being asked, aged about 9, to improve the punctuation of a small-ad: 'Table for sale by lady with wobbly leg'. Our text at the time was Ridout's _English Today_ but surely he would have seen the unlikely nature of such a formulation? Perhaps the teacher made it up.

Comment: @Michael: I hadn't seen that 'Jewish mother' joke before, and I'm a bit embarrassed to admit that I spent several seconds trying to google the *rest* of the joke before it dawned on me! (Made me laff tho, when I finally got it, so ty for brightening my day! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the 'rest' of the joke can be just 'Shouted on Florida beach by Jewish mother:'

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey: Actually, I noticed the name "Isaac Asimov" in the first few results returned by googling the punch line - so being a fan, I checked [that one](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Isaac_Asimov_s_Treasury_of_Humor/nFdOG5JxWZoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22My+son+the+doctor+is+drowning%22&pg=PA28&printsec=frontcover) out. Turns out *he* had a "follow-up" joke about Jewish sons becoming ***nuclear physicists instead of doctors***, to reduce their chances of having to be the fall guy in this joke - and *that* was what pretty much "spoon-fed" me the humour!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - that may explain where the rabbi got the joke from, as I know he is an old-school SF fan. He also told me a Monica Lewinsky joke, which I shall not repeat here, which I later told to a senior Jewish judge, not without some initial trepidation. He laughed uproariously, thanked me, and said it would feature in his next after-dinner speech.